# Function graph (timestamped entry and exit) for both user, library and kernel space in Linux?

Tags: linux, debugging, trace

I'm writing this more-less in frustration - but who knows, maybe there's a way for this too...

I would like to analyze what happens with a function from ALSA, say `snd_pcm_readi`; for that purpose, let's say I have prepared a small `testprogram.c`, where I have this:

```
void doCapture() {
  ret = snd_pcm_readi(handle, buffer, period_size);
}
```

The problem with this function is that it eventually (should) hook into `snd_pcm_readi` in the shared system library `/usr/lib/libasound.so`; from there, I believe via `ioctl`, it would somehow communicate to `snd_pcm_read` in the kernel module `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/sound/core/snd-pcm.ko` -- and that should ultimately talk to whatever `.ko` kernel module which is a driver for a particular soundcard.

Now, with the organization like above, I can do something like:

```
valgrind --tool=callgrind --toggle-collect=doCapture ./testprogram
```

... and then `kcachegrind callgrind.out.12406` does indeed reveal a relationship between `snd_pcm_readi`, `libasound.so` and an `ioctl` (*I cannot get the same information to show with `callgrind_annotate`*) - so that somewhat covers userspace; but that is as far as it goes. Furthermore, it produces a *call graph*, that is to say general caller/callee relationships between functions (possibly by a count of samples/ticks each function has spent working as scheduled).

However, what I would like to get instead, is something like the output of the Linux `ftrace` tracer called `function_graph`, which provides a timestamped entry and exit of traced kernel functions... example from [ftrace: add documentation for function graph tracer [LWN.net]](http://lwn.net/Articles/334530/):

```
$ cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace
# tracer: function_graph
#
#      TIME       CPU  DURATION                  FUNCTION CALLS
#       |         |     |   |                     |   |   |   |
 2105.963678 |   0)               |      mutex_unlock() {
 2105.963682 |   0)   5.715 us    |        __mutex_unlock_slowpath();
 2105.963693 |   0) + 14.700 us   |      }
 2105.963698 |   0)               |      dnotify_parent() {
```

(*NB: newer `ftrace` documentation seems to **not** show a timestamp at first for the `function\_graph`, only duration - but I think it's still possible to modify that*)

With `ftrace`, one can filter so one can only trace functions in a given kernel module - so in my case, I could add the functions of `snd-pcm.ko` and whatever `.ko` module is the soundcard driver, and I'd have whatever I find interesting in kernel-space covered. But then, I lose the link to the user-space program (*unless I explicitly `printf` to `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_marker`, or do a `trace_printk` from user-space `.c` files*)

Ultimately, what I'd like, is to have the possibility to specify an executable, possibly also library files and kernel modules - and obtain a timestamped function graph (with indented/nested entry and exit per function) like `ftrace` provides. Are there any alternatives for something like this? (Note I can live without the function exits - but I'd really like to have timestamped function entries)

---

As a PS: it seems I actually found something that fits the description, which is the `fulltrace` application/script:

[fulltrace [andreoli@Github]](https://github.com/andreoli/fulltrace/blob/master/README.md)

> fulltrace traces the execution of an ELF program, providing as output a full trace of its userspace, library and kernel function calls. ...
>   (prerequisites) the following kernel configuration options and their dependencies must be set as enabled (=y): FTRACE, TRACING_SUPPORT, UPROBES, UPROBE_EVENT, FUNCTION_GRAPH_TRACER.

Sounds perfect - but the problem is, I'm on Ubuntu 11.04, and while this `2.6.38` kernel luckily has `CONFIG_FTRACE=y` enabled -- its `` /boot/config-`uname -r` ``
 doesn't even mention `UPROBES` :/ And since I'd like to avoid doing kernel hacking, unfortunately I cannot use this script...

(*Btw, if UPROBES were available, (as far as I understand) one sets a trace probe on a symbol address (as obtained from say `objdump -d`), and output goes again to `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace` - so some custom solution would have been possible using UPROBES, even without the `fulltrace` script*)

So, to narrow down my question a bit - is there a solution, that would allow simultaneous user-space (incl. shared libraries) and kernel-space "function graph" tracing, but where `UPROBES` are not available in the kernel?

Comment: UPROBES is merged to 3.5. If you want function call graph you probably need to recompile the kernel anyway. Call graph generation (regardless of which tool you are using) depends on the frame pointer being used, which is normally disabled in the kernel.

Comment: Cheers @n.m. - thanks for the heads up! It seems I'll probably have to go that way...